"Error 404: The resource is not found on this computer" when deploy Django Web Service to Render.com, deployment is successful, site is Live w/green
I have a Django web application that works great when testing it in local server.  It uses generics.APIViews, and there is no index.html file and no static files to be served.
I've read and abided by all the Render.com docs to deploy to Render.com including https://docs.render.com/deploy-django and https://docs.render.com/web-services#port-binding.
I suspect it has something to do with port binding.  Been researching different ways to make it work.  I'm new to Django so probably something simple I'm missing:
Below a shot of my settings.py:
import os
import dj_database_url
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', default='your secret key')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
#DEBUG = True
DEBUG = 'RENDER' not in os.environ

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

RENDER_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME = os.environ.get('RENDER_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME')
if RENDER_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(RENDER_EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME)



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'API'
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'jproj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'jproj.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
                'default': dj_database_url.config(
                        
                    default='postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/jproj',
                    conn_max_age=600 )
                }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/static-files/

#STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if not DEBUG:
    # Tell Django to copy static assets into a path called `staticfiles` (this is specific to Render)
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    # Enable the WhiteNoise storage backend, which compresses static files to reduce disk use
    # and renames the files with unique names for each version to support long-term caching
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

My environment variables in Render.com:





can you share an error

Yes, I've now shared a screenshot of the error log from Render.com.  Thanks for your comment.

issue is because you may have not configured your url.py for the root url, in this case, "/".  By default, Django REST framework won't respond to the root URL unless you explicitly configure it to do so.

Ok, I've posted two screenshots of how I set up my urls.py files in both the "project" and in the "API app".  I'm using the "from django.urls import path,include" way of handling the routing.  Should I have a "/" inside the "" in "urlpatterns = [
path("", include("API.urls")),
]" in my projects urls.py file?
